# Send email from my domain using SendGrid on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, email, sendgrid

I have a Rails 4 app which is being hosted by Heroku on my_domain.com. I'm using free SendGrid to send emails, but no matter what settings I use all the emails are sent from `my_app@heroku.com`. How can set the settings so that emails are sent from `automated@my_domain.com`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `app/mailers/your_mailer.rb` and add the following line under `class  YourMailer < ActionMailer::Base`

```
default from: "automated@my_domain.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try control-shift-F (which will pull up a search for your entire codebase). Search for "my_app@heroku.com" and you may be able to find where this variable is being set. Let me know if this doesn't work and I will try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Set in your production.rb,

```
 config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It didn't fix the problem. The sender is still: `my_app@heroku.com via sendgrid.info`. Any other ideas as how to got about fixing it?